# Setting WPF text to TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, flowdocument

I know that `TextBlock` can present a `FlowDocument`, for example:

```
<TextBlock Name="txtFont">
     <Run Foreground="Maroon" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="24">Courier New 24</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

I would like to know how to set a `FlowDocument` that is stored in a variable to a `TextBlock`.
I am looking for something like:

```
string text = "<Run Foreground="Maroon" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="24">Courier New 24</Run>"
txtFont.Text = text;
```

However, The result of the code above is that the XAML text is presented unparsed.

---

**EDIT:** I guess my question was not clear enough. What I'm really trying to achive is:

1. The user input some text into a *RichTextBox*.
2. The application saves the user input as `FlowDocument` from the *RichTextBox*, and serializes it to the disk.
3. The `FlowDocument` is deserialized from the disk to the variable *text*.
4. Now, I would like to be able to present the user text in a `TextBlock`.

Therefore, as far as I understand, creating a new *Run* object and setting the parameters manually will not solve my problem.

---

The problem is that serializing *RichTextBox* creates *Section* object, which I cannot add to *TextBlock.Inlines*. Therefore, it is not possible to set the deserialized object to *TextProperty* of *TextBlock*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that TextBlock can present FlowDocument

What makes you think that ? I don't think it's true... The content of a `TextBlock` is the `Inlines` property, which is an `InlineCollection`. So it can only contain `Inline`s... But in a `FlowDocument`, the content is the `Blocks` property, which contains instances of `Block`. And a `Block` is not an `Inline`

Answer (score 5):

create and add the object as below:

```
        Run run = new Run("Courier New 24");
        run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Maroon);
        run.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier New");
        run.FontSize = 24;
        txtFont.Inlines.Add(run);
```

Comment: run.Foreground = Brushes.Maroon;

Answer (score 0):

If your *FlowDocument* has been *deserialized*, it means that you have an object of type `FlowDocument`, right? Try setting the Text property of your TextBlock to this value. Of course, you cannot do this with `txtFont.Text = ...`, since this only works for strings. For other types of objects, you need to set the DependencyProperty directly:

```
txtFont.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, myFlowDocument)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we are setting the look of a textblock by assigning a style on-the-fly.

```
    // Set Weight (Property setting is a string like "Bold")
    FontWeight thisWeight = (FontWeight)new FontWeightConverter().ConvertFromString(Properties.Settings.Default.DealerMessageFontWeightValue);

    // Set Color (Property setting is a string like "Red" or "Black")
    SolidColorBrush thisColor = (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(Properties.Settings.Default.DealerMessageFontColorValue);

    // Set the style for the dealer message
    // Font Family Property setting  is a string like "Arial"
    // Font Size Property setting is an int like 12, a double would also work
    Style newStyle = new Style
    {
        TargetType = typeof(TextBlock),
        Setters = {
            new Setter 
            {
                Property = Control.FontFamilyProperty,
                Value = new FontFamily(Properties.Settings.Default.DealerMessageFontValue)
            },
            new Setter
            {
                Property = Control.FontSizeProperty,
                Value = Properties.Settings.Default.DealerMessageFontSizeValue
            },
            new Setter
            {
                Property = Control.FontWeightProperty,
                Value = thisWeight
            },
            new Setter
            {
                Property = Control.ForegroundProperty,
                Value = thisColor
            }
        }
    };

    textBlock_DealerMessage.Style = newStyle;
```

You can eliminate the style section and set properties directly, but we like keeping things bundled in the style to help us organize the look throughout the project.

```
textBlock_DealerMessage.FontWeight = thisWeight;
```

HTH.